# Logging in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am able to develop  a pipeline  which reads from kafka does some transformations and write the output to kafka sink as well as parque sink. I would like adding effective logging to log the  intermediate results of the transformation  like in a regular streaming application.

One option I see is to log the `queryExecutionstreams` via

```
df.queryExecution.analyzed.numberedTreeString
```

or

```
logger.info("Query progress"+ query.lastProgress)
logger.info("Query status"+ query.status)
```

But this doesn't seem to have a way to see the business specific messages on which the stream is running on.

Is there a way how I can add more logging info like the data which it's processing?

Answer (score 2):

i found some options to track the same .Basically we can name our streaming Queries using  df.writeStream.format("parquet")
.queryName("table1")

The query name table1 will be printed in the  Spark Jobs Tab against the Completed Jobs list in the Spark UI from which you can track the status for each of the streaming queries

2) Use the  ProgressReporter API  in structured streaming to collect more stats